# Is there an AD SimpleMemberShip provider for MVC4?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there an AD SimpleMemberShip provider for MVC4? Or a good third party one I can download from somewhere? All the docs seem to focus on SQL server.

Or do I have to write my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no equivalent of the SimpleMembershipProvider for Active Directory. You will have to write your own. If you use the full blown Membership, you could use `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` which is specifically designed to work with AD.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, that's the one I use in MVC3, but it looks like the default web app template (for example, in the Logoff method) in MVC4 is geared towards SimpleMembership. Thanks for the answer Darin. I'll accept it when it lets me (10 mins apparently)